# How to enable more than one interrupt AVR

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, atmel

I am using an ATmega88PA to look for pin changes on 2 pins. I would like to use PCINT0 and PCINT2 although I have a lot of other pins open if I need to use a different pin. I have been messing around with things and was able to get PCINT0 to work properly, my problem came when I was trying to get PCINT2 to work.

If I define and set up PCINT2 the same way that I did to get PCINT0 to work nothing happens. I have tried this even in a new program just to see if something else was interfering in some way but that did not solve anything. I even got rid of PCINT0 all together to see if i could get PCINT2 to work on its own but I was still not able to.

Here is the code that I had for PCINT0

```
DDRC = 0x20; // PORTC,5 is now output
   sbi(PORTC,5);
   USART_Init(51);
   lcd_init(LCD_DISP_ON);
   lcd_clrscr();

PCICR |= (1 << PCIE0);
PCMSK0 |= (1 << PCINT0);
```

If I change everything to PCMSK2 and PCINT2 nothing happens when I trigger the pin. here is a link to the data sheet for the ATmega88PA [Datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Can you post the code you are trying to use to enable PCINT2?

Comment: @BeenCoding2Long I dont know what to do for PCINT2. This is what I was trying though.
PCICR |= (1 << PCIE2);
PCMSK2 |= (1 << PCINT18);

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem might be largely due to the slightly confusing names of the various register flags. If you stare at the datasheet long enough, you'll notice that PCIE2 and PCMSK2 do not control PCINT2. They actually control PCINT16 to PCINT23.

PCINT0-PCINT7 (which includes PCINT2, which you want) are controlled by PCIE0 in PCICR (which you already set) and PCMSK0 (not PCMSK2 which you mention in your last comment.)

So, to fix your problem, all you need to do is change your last line to:

PCMSK0 |=(1 << PCINT0) | (1 << PCINT2)

Disclaimer: I have not had a chance to test this on real hardware. Please double-check the datasheet.

Hope this helps.